# How to change ffmpeg process priority?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, process

I'm trying to find a way to set ffmpeg process priority. Server converts incoming videos to different resolutions, new videos should have higher priority and be converted faster, than existing processes.

It should work similar to SJF (Shortest Job First) or LIFO (Last In First Out) algorithms.

Is there any way to do it with ffmpeg?

I spawn processes this like

`ffmpeg -i "${video_path}" -strict experimental -movflags faststart -vf "${resolution}" "${output_path}" >> "${ffmpeg_log}" 2>&1`

Note:

I have already tested `nice` based solution. It looks like it doesn't work. I spawned 2 ffmpeg process with priority 10 and -10, and that which was spawned earlier was completed earlier

Comment: Hi Mike, it seems you used the wrong account to post this question. To have them merged, see here: https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 3):

You simply call [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) before calling the process, along with the niceness value.

The man pages for `nice` will show you how to figure out exactly how 'nice' a process is, i.e. lower values == less nice, higher priority.

`nice --5 "ffmpeg -i...."` would launch ffmpeg with a nice value of -5, making it higher priority than something with a nice value of -1.

0 is normally the default, a higher value than this means you'd have less than default priority.

Comment: There's also `renice` – to affect a process that is already running.

Comment: The traditional '-increment' option has been deprecated (found here: `nice --5`). See man page of `nice`. Use `nice -n -5 ...` for a nice value of -5.
(Rant: I can not edit the answer since the change would not have the required 6 characters. That stupid policy already caught me a few times when trying to improve answers in the Stack universe. Just not in the mood right now to artificially improve the answer more than necessary.)